# Starting out with Fstar

Tags: functional-programming, dependent-type, fstar

I have been reading about F-star from some of its paper and the F-star tutorial, but I find myself quite lost trying to understand its concepts. For example, dependently type, Dijkstra monads, etc.

What are the pre-requisites to properly understand and learn about F-star?
Any explanation of links to any resource will be helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

You might find the following general resources helpful.

https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/

https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540208549

http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/

None of these are particularly specific to F*, but some of the concepts you learn there will provide useful background.